# Passing Contract's variable as param constructure of another contract when migrate truffle

Tags: truffle, erc-20, openzeppelin

This are my contracts:

Token.sol

```
contract Token is ERC20 {
    address public admin;
    constructor () ERC20("SimpleToken", "SIM") {
        admin = msg.sender;
        _mint(msg.sender, 10000 * (10 ** uint256(decimals())));
    }
```

Pool.sol

```
contract Pool {

    IERC20 public _token;
    constructor (address token) {
        _token = IERC20(token);
    }
}
```

inital migrate file

```
const Token = artifacts.require('Token');
const Pool = artifacts.require('Pool');

module.exports = async function (deployer) {
  await deployer.deploy(Token).then(function(){
    return deployer.deploy(Pool, Token.admin)
  });
};
```

I want to pass the admin variable of the Token contract (sender who initialize the Token contract, not the address of Token contract). But I dont know how to do so. I need some help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are taking wrong.
If you are going to get the initializer address, you can use **msg.sender** in Pool contract.
And as I can see in the Pool contract, you should pass the address of the Token contract, not the initializer address.